# How To Get The Current Year Using Vba

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am trying to get the current year using VBA. Is there any pre-build function available to find out the current year?

Comment: Even though it's in Excel, if you are asking how to do something in VBA, it relates more to programming. I'm migrating this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23479761/630284

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
Year(Date)
```

`Year()`: Returns the year portion of the date argument.
`Date`: Current date only.

Explanation of both of these functions from [here](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html).

Comment: This gives a Compile error: "`Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`"

Comment: For those who might get this error that I received above: I found it was because I had a label whose `Name` value was also "Year". A little troubling that VBA let me name something the same as what a reserved keyword is... Changing my label to "YearLabel" allowed me to use `Year(Date)` successfully.

Comment: Thanks for adding that, @TylerH.

Answer (score 10):

Try `=Year(Now())` and format the cell as `General`.