# How to get current Year Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi  I am using this past thread [How To Get The Current Year Using Vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244354/how-to-get-the-current-year-using-vba)

The answer was to use `Year(Date)` so I implemented it like this:

```
Dim a As Integer
a = Year(Date)
```

But when I tried to use it, I am getting an error

> `Runtime 13 : Type Mismatch`

Comment: Show the entire line of code that is throwing the error.  We have no idea how to solve it based on how little you have shown.

Comment: I'm thinking `Date` was really supposed to be a placeholder.  Try `Year(Now())`.

Comment: @cHao no, `Year(Date)` is valid syntax.  The problem is likely the assignment.

Comment: `Dim a As Integer
 a = Year(Date)`   this was giving error

Comment: Even with `Year(Now())` had same error... but solved with `DatePart`

Comment: @sharkantipav considering that works perfectly for me, you probably had a different issue somewhere else that was fixed when you changed the code to use `DatePart`

Comment: I agree with @psubsee2003, this resolution seems totally coincidental. Something else is happening.

Comment: this is weird.. thx anyway

Comment: You could also try `VBA.Year(Date)`. Or it is possible you have a missing library reference. (Review under Tools > References in the VBE).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Excel VBA, you want to use `DATEPART`.  Assuming that the data that you're trying to get the year from is valid (which is hard to know from the little information in your question).

From [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datepart.php):

> **MS EXCEL: DATEPART FUNCTION (VBA)**
>
> Learn how to use the Excel DATEPART function with syntax and examples.
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The Microsoft Excel DATEPART function returns a specified part of a
>   given date.
>
> **SYNTAX**
>
> The syntax for the Microsoft Excel DATEPART function is:
>
> DatePart( interval, date, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear] )

and this specific example:

> DatePart("yyyy", "15/10/2012")   would return 2012

Comment: just did it... it did nt want to for the 1st 10 min ;)

Comment: While this answer ultimately solves the OP's problem, I feel this is misleading as it really doesn't answer the "why am I getting this error" problem.  The OP's attempted solution appears to be perfectly valid so the fact that this fixed the problem appears to be coincidental.

Comment: I do, hwoever, think this would be an excellent answer on the question that the OP linked.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't read this as a "why am I getting this error" but just looking at the heading "How to get current Year Using VBA".  Either way, the OP is happy, nothing else to see here.

Comment: @DanAndrews if that was how you interpretted the question, then it was a duplicate and should have been closed as such.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I do not disagree with you.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your type mismatch is somewhere else because `Year(Date)` is valid. The other option is to use `Year(Now)`

I suspect you have declared the variable you are trying to assign to as something weird because VBA will make a lot of bizarre casts for you

```
Dim a As String
a = Year(Now)   ' "2014"

Dim b As Double
b = Year(Now)   '2014

Dim c As Integer
c = Year(Now)   '2014

Dim d As Date
d = Year(Date)  '#7/6/1905#

Dim e
e = Year(Now)   ' 2014 (implicitly cast to integer)
```

Be sure that you have `Option Explicit` set at the top of your module and you compile the code.

Comment: I tried with both.... and got the same error at  that line... i even tried something like `a=Year(Date)` same error

Comment: what is your data type for `a`?

Comment: Tried `integer`, `string`, `double`  same error

Comment: and it is in fact on this line of code? you're not guessing? what else is in your function? are you able to make another sub in a blank module and paste my code in and have it run with errors?